# Algebraic cobordism (of a point) outside the geometric diagonal

Tags: algebraic-k-theory, stable-homotopy, cobordism, motivic-homotopy

This question is about the state of current knowledge regarding Voevodsky's algebraic cobordism of a point $\mathrm{MGL}^{*,*}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)$. That the geometric diagonal $\mathrm{MGL}^{2*,*}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)$ is isomorphic to the Lazard ring $\mathbb{L}$ if $char(k)=0$ has been shown by Levine using the Hopkins-Morel isomorphism. For positive characteristic fields, Hoyois showed the same isomorphism holds after inverting the characteristic exponential. It is also well-known that $\mathrm{MGL}^{n,n}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)$ is identified with the Milnor $K$-theory of a field.

Spitzweck, in [Algebraic Cobordism in mixed characteristic, section 7](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2542), computed some of the homotopy groups $\pi_{p,q}\mathrm{MGL}_S$ of the algebraic cobordism spectrum in the stable homotopy category $SH(S)$ over $S$, $S$ being the spectrum of a Dedekind domain of mixed characteristic. For instance, he described the cases $(p,q)=(2n+1,n)$, $(n+1,n)$. My question is:

> 1. Are similar descriptions already known in the case $S=\mathrm{Spec}\,k$?
> 2. For $S=\mathrm{Spec}\,k$, is it known that $\mathrm{MGL}^{2n+i,n}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)$ vanishes for $i\geq 1$.

Comment: Are you only interested in the characteristic zero case? Some of the results you recalled are only known in that case.

Comment: Even though characteristic zero is what I am mainly interested in, I am curious about positive characteristics too. These questions can be asked after inverting the characteristic exponential, as in your paper referred above. I am sorry I should have mentioned this in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to both question is yes, provided you invert $p$ in characteristic $p$ (though conjecturally this is not necessary). In fact, as far as I can see, all of Spitzweck's computations apply to fields as well. He only assumes mixed characteristic because some of the arguments are more difficult in that case (e.g. Corollary 5.9). So for example $\mathrm{MGL}^{2n-1,n}(\operatorname{Spec} k) = k^\times \otimes L_{1-n}$ and $\mathrm{MGL}^{n-1,n}(\operatorname{Spec} k)$ is an extension of $H^{n-1,n}(\operatorname{Spec} k)$ by a quotient of $K_{n+1}^M(k)$.

For the vanishing see also this question: [The vanishing of $MGL^{2n+i,n}(X)$; do spectra of smooth projective varieties generate $SH_{l}$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111849/the-vanishing-of-mgl2ni-nx-do-spectra-of-smooth-projective-varieties-ge)

It's worth noting that the vanishing of $\mathrm{MGL}^{p,q}(\operatorname{Spec}k)$ for $p>q$ and the computation $\mathrm{MGL}^{n,n}(\operatorname{Spec}k)=K_n^M(k)$ hold without inverting the characteristic (they come from Morel's results about the sphere spectrum).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I noticed that some of my questions are already answered in the thread you mentioned. I am, however, a bit confused regarding the vanishing of $\mathrm{MGL}^{p,q}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)$ for $p>q$ as $\mathrm{MGL}^{2n,n}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)$ or $\mathrm{MGL}^{2n-1,n}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)$ are not zero.

Comment: They are zero if $n$ is positive!

Comment: Are the results on $\mathrm{MGL}^{2n-1,n}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)$ and $\mathrm{MGL}^{n-1,n}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)$ that you mention written down somewhere? Or they are deduced from Spitzweck's results?

Comment: Ah! ok! I was assuming in my mind that $\mathrm{MGL}^{p,q}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)$ vanishes for $q<0$ like motivic cohomology. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I have only quoted 7.6 and 7.7 in Spitzweck.

Comment: Would you consider it reasonable to conjecture that there is an isomorphism (at least after inverting characteristic exponential) $\mathrm{MGL}^{p,q}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)\simeq\oplus_{0\leqslant j\leqslant q-p}H\mathbb{Z}^{p+2j,q+j}(\mathrm{Spec}\,k)\otimes \mathbb{L}_j$, where $\mathbb{L}_j$ is the degree $j$ homogenous piece of the Lazard ring?

Comment: If this were true you'd have an analogous result for K-theory, by tensoring with $\mathbb Z[\beta^{\pm 1}]$. But it's true for finite fields, by the slice spectral sequence.

Comment: Do you mean that the result for K-theory is true only for finite fields or not known for infinite fields?

Comment: I mean that your conjecture is true for finite fields but false in general.